# Install Jammer Locate Java Runtime

Tags: java, installation, setup-project

I am stuck with my Install Jammer setup creation for an application that requires Java and MySQL.

The problem is, when I don't have a Java version in the system , it prompts the user to select the java path and automatically goes to the Browser window to download the Java.

This occurs when I use the built in java checking action **Locate Java Runtime**

I don't need the setup to automatically open the Java download path, instead shows the Link to Java download in a new pane. How can I resolve this?

Please any one do reply as soon as possible as I need the solution so early.

Thanks in advance.